# Create multiple listener for same ip and port different by sitename

Tags: windows-server-2003, isa-server

I have a windows server 2003r2 and ISA Server 2004
current i created 2 rule on ISA Server

1. Port:80 redirecting to ServerOne where runing webapp1
2. Port:85 redirecting to ServerTwo where running webapp2

and i have 2 domains 1:- webapp1.com and 2:- webapp2.com
when request comes on IsaServer with port 80 it's redirecting to ServerOne and when request comes with port 85 it's redirecting to ServerTwo which is fine.

problem is i have only one Public IP and 
The domain sites does not allowing me to add type A host record with port 85

is it possible in ISA server to listen domain name and redirect by domain 
for example

1. request comes with webapp1.com:80 redirect to ServerOne
2. request comes with webapp2.com:80 redirect to ServerTwo

any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it's a late answer, but it's also a very late time to be running that OS and app combination. Upgrade to something built this decade! (Had you noticed the decade is nearly over?)

With that out of the way, you can do what you want with Web Publishing rules. It sounds like you've used a port-specific Server Publishing rule, which doesn't allow for multiple sites per port. Using a Web Publishing rule uses (and/or creates) a Web Listener, which binds to (say) ports 80 and 443. The Web Listener is usable across multiple hostnames and sites, and the Web Pub rules use HTTP headers to disambiguate them and route them to the correct back-end site.

It normally takes some fiddling to work out whether you need to use Link Translation as well or not, but it's pretty easy when you get the hang of it.

But seriously: Time to upgrade - you can get free forward/reverse proxies with much the same feature set these days.